# A closed set inside a compact is compact

Tags: general-topology, compactness

So I know that if $(X, \tau)$ is compact and $A$ is a closed set of $\tau$, then $A$ is compact. However if $(X, \tau)$ is not compact and $A$ is a compact subset of $X$, and $B \subset A$ where $B$ is a closedset, then $B$ is a compact of $A$. Is it a compact of $(X, \tau)$ though?

**Note**: When I talk about $A$ as a topological space, it has the topology induced by $\tau$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compactness is a property that a topological space has on its own, it is not relative to some other space in which it is embedded, unlike closedness or openness. Therefore, in this case, $B$ is a closed subset of $A$, which is compact, so $B$ is also compact, and this fact is not influenced from $B$ being a subspace of $A$ or $X$. To clarify, recall the definition of compactness:

> A topological space $(X,\tau)$ is compact if, for every collection $\mathcal A$ of open subsets of $X$ whose union is $X$ ($\mathcal A$ is thus called an *open cover* of $X$), there exist finitely many elements of $\mathcal A$ whose union is still $X$ (we say that $\mathcal A$ has a finite subcover).

Now, if you have a subset $Y$ of $X$, you can define a similar notion of compactness for $Y$:

> We say that $Y$ is a compact subset of $(X,\tau)$ if, for every collection $\mathcal A$ of open subsets of $X$ whose union contains $Y$, there exist finitely many elements of $\mathcal A$ whose union still contains $Y$.

Actually, it turns out that, if we equip $Y$ with the subspace topology induced by $(X,\tau)$, the two notions are equivalent, that is:

> $Y$ is a compact subset of $(X,\tau)\iff Y$, with the topology induced by $(X,\tau)$, is compact.

You can try to prove this last result by yourself as an exercise, you need to use the definition of induced topology. I hope this clarifies why compactness is a property of a space, that does not change if you embed it in some other space.

Answer (score 3):

Being compact doesn't depend upon the larger space. That is: is $Z\subset W$ and if $\tau$ is a topology on $W$ such that $(W,\tau)$ is compact, then $Z$ is compact with respect to the subspace topology if and only if it is a compact subset of $W$.

So, since $A$ is compact and $B$ is a closed subset of $A$, $B$ is compact too.

Comment: This is true but I think this discussion is not really relevant to this question.

Comment: @Hermis14 Why not? It follows from what I wrote that$$B\text{ is compact}\iff B\text{ is a compact subset of }A\iff B\text{ is a compact subset of }X.$$

Comment: I am sorry, I misread the question!